# Is there a way to share a background between Grid items?

Tags: css, html, background-image, css-grid

I'd simply like to have background-image use the space of two or more Grid items.

I've thought of using the container element but what if I just wanted to use a background-image for two items rather than the entire element container?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <advert></advert>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
header  {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;

}

header > a  {
  color: black;
}

advert  {
  grid-area: advert;
  background-image: url(./mi-vr-5.jpg);
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: 30%;
  background-size: 1000px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

I added a div (.sub) to the 2 elements that are using the same background. it is duplicated. I posted another answer with a different outcome.

```css
    header  {
      grid-area: header;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: wrap;
      flex: 0 1 auto;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 1em 0 1em 0;

    }
    
   .sub{
      background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/11/22/42/peacock-feathers-3013486_1280.jpg)
   }

    header > a  {
      color: black;
    }

    advert  {
      grid-area: advert;
      background-image: url(./mi-vr-5.jpg);
      background-position-x: 50%;
      background-position-y: 30%;
      background-size: 1000px
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <header>"{HEADER - I AM THE HEADER - HEADER}"</header>
          <div class="sub">
            <main>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no duo altera ornatus, omittam postulant mea ea. In eius nobis quaerendum nec, est saepe deserunt percipitur ei. Stet accusam consequuntur te eam, posse discere vix ex. Per ne accusam molestie.

</p>
            
            </main>
          </div>
            <advert>"{ADVERT - BUY THIS NOW - ADVERT}"</advert>
          <div class="sub">
            <aside><p>Docendi conclusionemque in duo, te qui persequeris definitiones. In has tollit rationibus complectitur. Cu eligendi aliquando qui, sea mentitum interpretaris ea. Veritus pertinax nam ei. Cum essent maiestatis at, eu mundi tempor blandit qui.

Modo quando consequat mel at. Ne per omnesque torquatos, his partiendo petentium cu. Ei possit mentitum consectetuer usu, ne aliquip laoreet eam, agam possit qui ei. Vis augue imperdiet eu, an sed electram urbanitas. Cu moderatius neglegentur mel, debitis tacimates an has. Cu nam vide malis, quas elaboraret omittantur ex quo.</p></aside>
          </div>
            <footer>"{FOOTER - I AM THE FOOTER - FOOTER}"</footer>
      </div>
```

Comment: Doesn’t this simply duplicate the picture? I’d like one picture across the two items.

Comment: apologies, editing now. @maximilian, please check out my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this?

I created a div (.sub) that wrapped around the first element you wanted affected, and the last element you wanted affected, plus everything in between. Then, I created a sub-div (.advert_back) around any element in between that you did not want to be affected by the initial div that will have the shared background. Once you create the shared background, add a plain background to the sub-div (in this case, I just made it white) so that it will "cover" the background that extends through it.

```css
header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

.sub {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/11/22/42/peacock-feathers-3013486_1280.jpg);
  color: #ffff;
}

header>a {
  color: black;
}

.advert_back {
  background-color: #ffff;
  color: black;
}

advert {
  grid-area: advert;
  background-image: url(./mi-vr-5.jpg);
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: 30%;
  background-size: 1000px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>"{HEADER - I AM THE HEADER - HEADER}"</header>
  <div class="sub">
    <main>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no duo altera ornatus, omittam postulant mea ea. In eius nobis quaerendum nec, est saepe deserunt percipitur ei. Stet accusam consequuntur te eam, posse discere vix ex. Per ne accusam molestie.
      </p>
    </main>
    <div class="advert_back">
      <advert>"{ADVERT - BUY THIS NOW - ADVERT}" </advert>
    </div>
    <aside>
      <p>Docendi conclusionemque in duo, te qui persequeris definitiones. In has tollit rationibus complectitur. Cu eligendi aliquando qui, sea mentitum interpretaris ea. Veritus pertinax nam ei. Cum essent maiestatis at, eu mundi tempor blandit qui. Modo
        quando consequat mel at. Ne per omnesque torquatos, his partiendo petentium cu. Ei possit mentitum consectetuer usu, ne aliquip laoreet eam, agam possit qui ei. Vis augue imperdiet eu, an sed electram urbanitas. Cu moderatius neglegentur mel,
        debitis tacimates an has. Cu nam vide malis, quas elaboraret omittantur ex quo.</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer>"{FOOTER - I AM THE FOOTER - FOOTER}"</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I’ll let you know tomorrow when I’m at my computer 